# Searching an association list by key

Tags: list, prolog, associations

I have implemented an association list in `swi-prolog` and I want to check if a specific key is in the list.
The structure of the code that I'm trying is the following:

```
get_assoc(Key,List,Value)
-if key exists 
    do this
-else 
    do that
```

However, it doesn't work. Is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: Regarding the same problem, I would like to ask if it is possible to use the association list and update it as a global variable with my predicates having access to it from everywhere.

Comment: Make you comment a separate question so that a specific answer can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

That predicate can be used to check the existence of a known/ground key:

```
?- list_to_assoc([foo-bar], Assoc),
   get_assoc(foo, Assoc, X).
   X = bar.

?- list_to_assoc([foo-bar], Assoc),
   get_assoc(baz, Assoc, _).
   false.
```

Should you wish to generate all keys in a assoc:

```
?- list_to_assoc([foo-bar, baz-1], Assoc),
   gen_assoc(Key, Assoc, _). % note gen_assoc/3 not get_assoc/3
   Key = foo ;
   Key = baz ;
   false.
```

To make an assoc global you can make it a fact, which can be unified in predicates, which could also use the if/else branching you mention.

```
my_assoc(Assoc) :- list_to_assoc([foo-bar], Assoc).
% or my_assoc(t(foo, bar, -, t, t)).

my_predicate(K, V) :-
    my_assoc(Assoc),
    gen_assoc(K, Assoc, V).

my_branching_predicate(Out) :-
    my_assoc(Assoc),
    ( get_assoc(foo, Assoc, _)
    -> Out = "foo exists"
    ; Out = "No Such Key"
    ).
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul , I managed to implement both solutions.
I'm currently facing another problem while executing the following code:
`(get_assoc(Line, Assoc, Value) -> Value1 is Value+1; Value1 is 1),
       put_assoc(Line, Assoc, Value1, Array),`
When I try to add the key: 3581 with value 1 and the key 2619 with value 1 the first pair is successfull while the second fails. I am providing a screenshot of the trace failure. [link](https://imgur.com/rh2hVlw)

Comment: As Paulo said: new problem → new question. Will be happy to answer, but comments aren't the place for it, it's too hard to read without proper formatting!

Comment: You are right, i just wanted to avoid spamming. I'll keep that in mind though, thanks!